# emacs prompting for github password

Tags: magit, osx, git

I've recently switched from spacemacs to radian and have suddenly run into magit prompting for my github password whenever I view the status of a repository (the repository is configured to use SSH). However, I am still able to update the repo's status in magit, as well as stage, commit, and push changes.

When I perform the same actions on the command line, I am not prompted for a password and it seems as if git is picking up the configuration correctly.

Emacs has the correct `SSH_AGENT_PID` and `SSH_AGENT_SOCK` present in `getenv`.

Backtrace after setting `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` is available at https://gist.github.com/peschkaj/c0c102f8a5d383f603e1319ba9e7395c

Environment is:

- Emacs 26.1
- macOS 10.13.6
- magit 2.13.0
- Using [radian](https://github.com/raxod502/radian) as the basis of emacs configuration

Comment: Is your remote repo using an `ssh` url, or an `https` one? What do you mean by "view the status of a repository"? Does that mean fetch, or literally just refresh the status buffer?

Comment: The repo is using ssh, and by view status I mean just refresh the status buffer.

Comment: I'm surprised you get a prompt just for the status buffer. Maybe this is a `ghub` thing? Could you `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit`, hit `C-g` at the prompt, and post the resulting backtrace?

Comment: @npostavs I've updated the question with the backtrace and magit version number.

Comment: Okay, the prompting is from `magit-gh-pulls`, not magit itself. I don't know much about it, but https://github.com/sigma/magit-gh-pulls/issues/111 and/or https://github.com/sigma/magit-gh-pulls/issues/121 seem related.

Comment: That's the solution, thank you! If you'd like to write it up and get the internet points, feel free. Otherwise I can post the solution myself later on today.

Comment: Go ahead and post it yourself; I can see that the problems described there look similar, but it's not really clear to me what the solution is.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this was to supply a github user *and* oauth-token in the git config

```
git config --global --add github.user <user>
git config --global --add github.oauth-token <token>
```

Once both the oauth token and username are in place, and emacs has been restarted, I'm no longer prompted for my username and password.